# Base de datos access corrupta: “Unrecognized Database Format”

Tags: java, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Buenas!

Estoy utilizando Microsoft Access 2007 para hacer mis practicas en casa junto a JAVA y VB.NET. Corri el programa que tenia hecho en VB.NET cuando de la nada me reprocha con el mensaje del titulo... intente volver a descargar la base de datos que tenia en mi nube y reemplazarla, pero me sale otro error distinto a este:

[image]

Y si intento abrir el que tengo en mi proyecto en JAVA me sale lo siguiente (el odioso mensaje):

[image]

Intente reinstalar el driver del access database para la version del 2007, pero el error persiste. Lei por ahi que la version de 32 bits de este driver no causa este problema, solo la de 64... pero actualmente estoy usando el de 32.

¿Saben lo mas gracioso de todo?, es que cuando ejecuto la version del programa en JAVA, corre normal como si nada estuviese ocurriendo. En cambio, si ejecuto la version del programa en VB.NET, de una vez me canta con el segundo error. Las demas bases de datos que tengo de otros programas si estan funcionando normal... solamente esta base de datos me ha dado este problema que desconosco como resolver. Pense en crearlo todo de nuevo, pero es que ni siquiera me deja importar datos ni ver las relaciones...

¿Cómo podria solucionar este pesado problema?

**Actualizacion**

A peticion dejo el codigo de ambas conexiones, tanto en VB.NET como en JAVA:

***VB.NET***

```
Module ModuleH
    Friend conexion As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Hospital.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")

    Friend Sub ConectarBD()
        Try
            conexion.Open()
            MsgBox("Pulse aceptar para confirmar la carga de datos.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conexion.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

***JAVA***

*Clase gestor* (Aqui inicializo el driver de UcanAccess y la direccion de la DB)

```
public class GestorDB {
private Connection conn;
private final String driver;

public GestorDB(String direccionDB) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+direccionDB);
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    return conn;
}
```

*Clase administrador* (Cargo la direccion de la DB)

```
public class Administrador {
private GestorDB gestor;
private String idActual;

public Administrador() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    gestor = new GestorDB("*******SaludParaTodos\\src\\Hospital.accdb");
    idActual = "";
}    

public Connection obtenerConexion(){
    return gestor.getConnection();
}
```

Vuelvo a resaltar lo que ocurre:

- La base de datos Hospital.accdb no puedo abrirla en el mismo Microsoft Access 2007 (me salen esos mensajes de error).
- El programa escrito en VB.NET no reconoce la base de datos (Arroja el mismo mensaje de la segunda imagen), mientras que la version del programa en JAVA si funciona totalmente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de Windows que estás usando?¿Haz verificado que tenga todas las actualizaciones importantes instaladas tanto de windows como de office? ¿Te es posible actualizar Access (ya hay tres versiones mas recientes)? ¿Has intentado lo que te ha sugerido Mauricio?

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver @Rubén, tuve que pasar mi Base de datos a otra computadora con Access 2013, crear una base de datos nueva e importar dichos datos a la DB nueva. . . Luego volvi al Access 2007, compacte la nueva DB y santo remedio.

Comment: Que bueno que lo resolviste. Lo que has hecho, por favor agrégalo como respuesta, pues la intención es que los comentarios sean temporales.

Comment: Pon el comentario en la solución, lo digo para que pueda servir en el futuro a otros que pudieran tener este mismo problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta:

1. Abrir Microsoft Access y selecciona la opción *"compactar y reparar la base de datos"*.
2. Intenta abrir tu base de datos con otra versión de Access (Ejemplo *ms-access 2010* o versiones superiores).
3. Es posible que tu equipo no cuente con los componentes de conexión a datos; en este caso, te recomiendo instalar [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734).

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución es un poco extensa, ya que necesite dos computadoras para hacerlo:

1. Como podrán ver, el problema de la base de datos corrupta inicio en una maquina con **Microsoft Access 2007**. Primero tome una copia de la base de datos corrupta y la guarde en un USB.
2. Siguiendo las distintas soluciones que dejo Mauricio, en especial la numero 2... use una segunda maquina con **Access 2013** para abrir la BD corrupta. Si intentaba visualizar las tablas y columnas, no me era posible, pero si me dejaba utilizar la opción de **importar base de datos de Access**.
3. Cree una base de datos nueva en la segunda maquina (**Access 2013**).
4. Utilize la opcion de **importar base de datos de Access**.
5. En la primera maquina con **Access 2007**, hice dos copias: Una DB para **VB.NET** y otra para **JAVA** (Hasta aqui se solucionaria todo para **VB.NET**).
6. Para que la DB de Access corra bien en **JAVA** se necesitaria primero seleccionar la opcion de **compactar y reparar**, ya que si pegas la DB como estaba, surgen errores en cuanto a la *indexación* de las columnas.

En realidad no necesitaba tampoco hacer mucho para JAVA ya que estoy usando **UcanAccess** y este no depende nada de nada de Microsoft Access, pero en cambio, **VB.NET** si...